# ORDER BY - Sorting the column consisting money with units

Tags: sql-server, sorting, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-server-2019

I have a stock related table in SQL with various columns, one being "Market Cap". This column is of "nvarchar" data-type and has values  such as **1.16T, 1.2B, 70.324 M , 8B, etc.**

where T= Trillion > B= Billion > M = Million

I need to sort these values in descending order.

*I tried this query:*

```
select MarketCap from StockSummary
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(MarketCap) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(MarketCap) = 1 THEN CAST(MarketCap AS float) ELSE 0 END,
    MarketCap DESC
```

*Output:*

```
Market Cap
700.394M
61.816B
6.983B
39.511B
28.996B
231.31M
2.112B
1.23T
```

The numbers are sorted in descending  order but it does not consider the units(T= Trillion > B= Billion > M = Million). Hence does not satisfy my requirements.

*Required Output:*

```
Market Cap
1.23T
61.816B
39.511B
28.996B
6.983B
2.112B
700.394M
231.31M
```

Can anyone suggest a query to resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Redesign your schema and enter the normalized values when writing to that table. This is a case, where numeric actually **is** numeric, so storing it as a text is not a good idea.

Comment: Why the question is tagged with MySQL? it does not support T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `patindex()` in concert with a `try_convert()`  we can get the value, then a simple `CASE` do resolve the scale.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Market Cap] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('700.394M')
,('61.816B')
,('6.983B')
,('39.511B')
,('28.996B')
,('231.31M')
,('2.112B')
,('1.23T')
 
Select *
 From @YourTable
 Order By try_convert(money,left([Market Cap],patindex('%[a-z]%',[Market Cap]+'a')-1))
          * case when [Market Cap] like '%M%' then 1000000 
                 when [Market Cap] like '%B%' then 1000000000 
                 when [Market Cap] like '%T%' then 1000000000000
                 else 1 end Desc
```

**Returns**

```
Market Cap
1.23T
61.816B
39.511B
28.996B
6.983B
2.112B
700.394M
231.31M
```

**EDIT**

Just another option

```
...
Order By try_convert(float,replace(replace(replace([Market Cap],'M','E6'),'B','E9'),'T','E12')) Desc
```

Comment: @SaiKushalG Always happy to help